# Compute the following limit if it exist $\lim_{(x, y) \to (0,0)} \frac{sin(xy)}{y}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$\lim_{(x, y) \to (0,0)} \frac{sin(xy)}{y}$

Solution:

$\lim_{(x, y) \to (0,0)} \frac{sin(xy)}{y} = \lim_{(x, y) \to (0,0)} \frac{sin(xy)}{xy} \lim_{(x, y) \to (0,0)} x = 1 \lim_{(x, y) \to (0,0)} x = 0$

could someone explain this solution please

Comment: It looks like you’re missing an $x$ in the second stage, but otherwise, this solution is simply multiplying by $\frac xx$.

Comment: Because $\displaystyle \lim_{z\rightarrow 0} \frac{sin(z)}{z}=1 $ hence to solve $\displaystyle \lim_{z\rightarrow 0} \frac{sin(q \cdot z)}{z}$ you doing $\displaystyle \lim_{z\rightarrow 0} \frac{q}{q} \cdot \frac{sin(q \cdot z)}{z}=q \cdot \displaystyle \lim_{z\rightarrow 0} \frac{sin(q \cdot z)}{q \cdot z}=q$ .